# MonacaのNiftyMBで初回起動時にPush通知のdevicetokenがセットされない（iphone)

Tags: monaca

MonacaのNiftyMBのプラグインを有効化して、マニュアル通りにコードを組み込んだのですが、
初回起動時（確認ダイアログが出る時）にダイアログでOKを押してるのですがNCMBのデータストアにデバイストークンが入りません。
確認ダイアログが出ない2回目以降だとデバイストークンが正常に入るのですが…。
上記はiOSでのみ発生しておりAndroidでは問題なく動いております。

色々試したのですが解決せず…。対処方法などありましたらご教授下さい。
以下対象のindex.htmlのコードになります。
const.jsではsetDeviceTokenの
PUSH_APPLICATION_KEY
PUSH_CLIENT_KEY
PUSH_SENDER_ID
を定義しております。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="js/const.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load",function()
    {

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function()
        {
            // デバイストークンを取得してinstallation登録
            //  * application_key, client_keyはニフティクラウドmobile backendから発行されたキーに置き換える
            //  * sender_idはGCMとの連携に必要な準備で取得したIDに置き換える

            //alert("application_key = " + application_key + " client_key = " + client_key + " sender_id = " + sender_id);

                    window.NCMB.monaca.setDeviceToken(
                                            PUSH_APPLICATION_KEY,
                                            PUSH_CLIENT_KEY,
                                            PUSH_SENDER_ID
                                            );




        }, false);


    },false);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 一旦loadイベントを消して、「js/const.js」にある「PUSH_APPLICATION_KEY」等を直接「setDeviceToken( )」に引数に渡してみたらどうでしょうか。また、確認はデバッグビルドして行っているのでしょうか・

Comment: もし依然解決されていないようでしたら、ニフティクラウドの公式ユーザーコミュニティ（https://github.com/NIFTYCloud-mbaas/UserCommunity）への投稿もご検討ください。